# Use One Identity for WebAPI and Asp.Net Core In different projects

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a solution that contains 2 dot net core projects :

1. Web API
2. Web Application(MVC)

The web application is a web API consumer.  My web application controller will use `httpclient` for getting data and I use razor for the client (no Javascript library such as Angular). I want to use `Microsoft identity` for authentication and recently I have read about `JWT` .

In which project should I add Microsoft Identity? (Because we need authentication for building a token in `JWT`)

If I must add it in the `Web API` project, how can I use identity when I need authentication in razor-- or somewhere else in the MVC project-- using `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` or `usermanager`?

Comment: Solved : I used IdentityServer4