# How can I Authenticate User from my old database in my new Asp.net core Web API?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-3.1

I have an asp.net core Web API project that I implemented for Signup and login in my android application .Now I want to create new android application but I don't want to create new tables in my new database for example tables user role and other for signup and login users ,My question is How can I create new .net core entity framework project and just create new tables for my new applications (for ex : products and producer and ...) but for authentication I use my old database for user authentication in my new web API ?

In my new Web API How can I use `Authorize` attribute and ...

***Old Asp.net Web API***

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit**
My question in another question is here

[Use One Identity for WebAPI and Asp.Net Core In different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896967/use-one-identity-for-webapi-and-asp-net-core-in-different-projects)

Comment: Here's an example from Microsoft that might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: My question is how can I use identity that I have on my old asp core web api on my new web api